# How do I fix weird offsets in bootstrap columns

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I make my pictures be aligned in the center when the screen shrinks to small to keep them side by side? I tried using columns, but it has a weird offset and it won't scoot to the side or align in a straight column when needed.
Here is my code:

```
                    <h2 class="text-center h2">Recent Projects</h2>

                </div>
                <div class="pics col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

                    <a href="350_project.html">
                        <img src="images/IMG_2579.JPG" width="450" height="350">
                    </a>

                    <h3 class="text-center">350 Project</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="pics col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

                    <a href="silk_screening.html">
                        <img src="images/IMG_0978.JPG" width="450" height="350">

                    </a>
                    <h3 class="text-center">Silk Screening</h3>               

                </div>
                <div class="pics col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

                    <a href="compost.html">

                        <img src="images/IMG_7793.JPG" width="450" height="350">

                    </a>
                    <h3 class="text-center">Food Feud</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="pics col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

                    <a href="terracycle.html">

                        <img src="images/Official_TerraCycle_Logo.png" width="450" height="350">

                    </a>

                    <h3 class="text-center">TerraCycle</h3>
                </div>
```

Comment: That's really weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use @media queries, making your div having something like "margin: auto" at a certain screen size or with a global parent div with "text-align:center".

Don't forget bootstrap grid item have a default "float:left" attribut, maybe you'll have to change it with @media queries.

I used it in my last project. I don't know it my objectives are compatibles with yours but it could help you.

```
    <div class="container_losange container_losange_mission col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8"> //content </div>
<div class="container_losange container_losange_mission float-right col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8"> //content </div>
<div class="container_losange container_losange_mission col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8"> //content </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="container_losange container_losange_mission float_none float-right col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8"> //content </div>
<div class="container_losange container_losange_mission float_none float-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8"> //content </div>
```

Then here I have 3 + 2 divs. The 2 last divs are center in the page because I make some modification :

```
    .section_mission {
       text-align: center;

       .container_losange_mission {
         display: inline-block;

         &.float_none {
            float: none;
         }
     }
```

float-right and float-left are just here for the specific design of the mobile view. (to have a "staggered" structure)
The clear div doesn't seems to be needed, I didn't remember why I used it.

```
/* Extra small devices (Phones (<768px)) */
@media(max-width:767px){
    .section_mission { 
       .container_losange_mission.float-right { float: right !important; }
       .container_losange_mission.float-left { float: left !important; }
    }
}
```

I don't know if my explications are usefull for you because I'm not sure it'll works with random number of elements..

---

If not, have a look on the CSS3 new functionnality FLEX:
http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/
http://www.alsacreations.com/tuto/lire/1493-css3-flexbox-layout-module.html
Could be usefull on this type of problem

Comment: Please include code samples :) - and use ` surrounding inline code :) - Explain how to use them, too. Until you do, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) is Mozilla's Guide.

Comment: Ok sry, I'm not used to answer on Stack ;) I will do that now.

Comment: Is that ok :s ? With a bad english ;)